# Убрать нулевые значения в массиве при отправке формы с сайта

Tags: javascript, form

Подскажите как обработать данные на странице в момент отправки данных формы.

Есть html форма:
(на самом деле тут сотни input, но привожу три, для примера)

```
<form method="post" action="/personal/order.form/" id="orderForm">

<input name="q[0]" type="number" min="0" max="99999" step="1" value="1" maxlength="5">
<input name="q[1]" type="number" min="0" max="99999" step="1" value="0" maxlength="5">
<input name="q[2]" type="number" min="0" max="99999" step="1" value="" maxlength="5">

</form>
```

Человек заполняет цифры в input'ах и отправляет форму. Далее php обрабатывает массив. Чтобы не перегружать пустыми значениями массив, хочу до отправки формы все нулевые и пустые значения убрать. Сейчас прилетает так:

```
array(1) {
    ["q"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
      [1]=>
      string(1) "0"
      [2]=>
      string(1) ""
```

А нужно без пустых значений:

```
array(1) {
    ["q"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
```

Перехватывают метод submit() для формы и могу обработать все input'ы и не понимаю, что делать дальше? Допустим могу создать нужный массив, но как его передать дальше!? Создать hidden input и заполнить его? Удалить с формы пустые input'ы!? но тогда визуально это на странице отобразится и запутает посетителя.

Подскажите, куда смотреть, что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Перед отправкой массива сделайте следующее:

```js
let q = ["1", "0", ""];
let fildered_q = q.map(parseInt).filter(Boolean)
console.log(fildered_q)
```

Comment: Обработать данные формы - это как раз без проблем. Как этот массив отправить вместе с формой и без ненужных input'ов?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX
или
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: Это тоже не то. Мне не нужно отправлять запросы AJAX или Fetch() методами, у меня простая html форма и нужно ее данные обработать/изменить и продолжить как делает это сама форма